# What would be the minimal Makefile for a C project?

Tags: makefile

I find plenty of answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474314/make-implicit-rule-to-link-c-project) that doesn't use the implicit rules.

The minimum I can write is this:

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC))

EXEC=a.exe

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ)
    $(RM) $(EXEC)
```

But I am sure I can remove the linking part as well.

Is it possible to reduce this Makefile a bit more?

**EDIT**

With the help of [Maxim Egorushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412080/maxim-egorushkin) I wrote this:

```
#Makefile
OBJS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))

EXEC=a

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)

all : $(EXEC)

clean :
    rm -f $(OBJS)

.PHONY: all clean
```

It does build my files, but it doesn't link anything:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o bar.o bar.c
cc    -c -o cow.o cow.c
cc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

What should I change?

The dummy source files are created as follow:

```
echo "int main() {return 0;}" > cow.c
touch foo.c bar.c cow.c
```

Comment: A minimal makefile is empty, using only predefined rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bare minimum would be:

```
all : a

a : a.o b.o c.o

clean :
    rm -f a a.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

It expects source files `a.c`, `b.c` and `c.c` to produce executable `a`:

```
$ touch a.c b.c c.c

$ make
cc    -c -o a.o a.c
cc    -c -o b.o b.c
cc    -c -o c.o c.c
cc   a.o b.o c.o   -o a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'a' failed
make: *** [a] Error 1
```

However, you do not get automatic header dependency generation with the [built-in GNU make rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules). [Extra 5 lines would be required for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44416055/412080).

Comment: You remove `a.c` in your clean target and you don't use the `$(RM)` variable

Comment: In my example I get `No rule to make target 'a', needed by 'all'`

Comment: @nowox I tested the code and it works. How do you invoke `make`?

Comment: It works because you don't need to link your objects. In my example I have several C files.

Comment: @nowox In this case just add a dependency: `a: a.o several.o c.o files.o`. It is explained in the first link in my post.

Comment: Any news from my last comment. I would like to give you reward, but I need your answer to be correct.

Comment: @nowox Did you overlook my previous comment?

Comment: Yes I did. I have just edited my question so you can show me how your solution works

Comment: To use the built-in rule for linking `a.exe` there must be an object file named `a.exe.o`, which in turn requires source file `a.exe.c`. Otherwise you need to use your own linking rule.

Comment: @nowox My answer is a working example. It requires a file named `a.c`.

Comment: @nowox Updated with more instructions for you.